# SSRS Get Last Row including zero values

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I need help on the SSRS Last Function.

Sample for the report that I build.
I need to get the value of the last row using LAST Function but after I use Last Function the value I get is 20 it disregards the 0 value for ID 4 which is the last record

```
ID    VALUE
1      10
2      0
3      20
4      0
```

> Last   20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that SSRS is giving you the correct value based on the scope which you're giving it. If you're not specifying a scope, then it will look at the lowest-level group it can find and return the last value in that group. Chances are, the data is being sorted at some point. Sorting in SSRS can occur in the SQL query, in the Tablix properties, or in the group properties.

If you have any sorting anywhere in the query or tablix or group that is sorting ascending, then depending on the scope specified for the Last() function, you would return 20.